# GWT. Convert JSON string to String[]

Tags: java, json, gwt

I have result JSON String: `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`. How I can convert it to `String[]` or `JsArrayString`? If it impossible what predefined data-structure I can use? I don't want to create my own class because it is redundant for simple string array.

Answer (score 2):

Since your string is a valid javascript array representation, you can use `unsafeEval` to get a javascript array:

```
JsArrayString a = JsonUtils.unsafeEval("['foo', 'bar', 'baz']");
```

Of course you have to be aware of security issues if you pass an arbitrary string to `unsafeEval`.

Otherwise, if your string were a valid JSON representation you could use `safeEval` instead which is more secure:

```
JsArrayString j = JsonUtils.safeEval("[\"foo\", \"bar\", \"baz\"]");
```

You can deal with `JsArrayString` easily in your java code, but if you prefer a `java.lang.String[]` you need to write some extra code like this (taken from the [jscollections](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-in-the-air/source/browse/trunk/src/net/ltgt/gwt/jscollections/client/JsArrays.java) library). Note that in production mode the transformation doesn't add any performance penalty.

```
public static String[] toArray(JsArrayString values) {
  if (GWT.isScript()) {
    return reinterpretCast(values);
  } else {
    int length = values.length();
    String[] ret = new String[length];
    for (int i = 0, l = length; i < l; i++) {
      ret[i] = values.get(i);
    }
    return ret;
  }
}

private static native String[] reinterpretCast(JsArrayString value) /*-{
  return value;
}-*/;
```

Finally you can use `java.util.List<String>` as well, but it can have some performance issues.

```
List<String> l = Arrays.asList(s)
```

Comment: There are built in methods and classes in GWT for handling JSON, there is no reason to bring JS into it.

Comment: Yep I know it and I have used it time ago. GWT-JSON objects use internally jsni to parse strings and generate a lot of java classes instead of Overlay classes which perform much better. In fact nowadays the tendency in GWT is to map json to java-beans using autobeans performing much better than old-fashion GWT-JSON. Anyway the user was asking about converting a string to a JsArrayString or a String and just that is my response.

Answer (score 0):

GWT actually has built in classes for working with JSON in the `com.google.gwt.json.clint` package. Note that you'll need to add

`<inherits name="com.google.gwt.json.JSON" />`

to your gwt.xml file.

```
JSONArray array = JSONParser.parseLenient("['foo', 'bar', 'baz']").isArray();
String[] resultArray = String[array.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
    resultArray[i] = array.get(i).isString().stringValue();
```